# How to initialize an array variable in an object's constructor

Tags: c++

Just compiling Test, the initializer list is not accepted:

```
class Test {
    public:
        Test() {
            array[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
        }

    private:
        int array[];
};
```

```
$ g++ -Wall -std=c++11 Test.h
Test.h: In constructor ‘Test::Test()’:
Test.h:7:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
    array[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
          ^
```

How can the array be initialized?

Comment: It can't be initialized. An `int array[];` class member is not valid C++. This is a gcc-only extension. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: consider using `std::vector` or `std::array`, since as previous comment states, you cannot achieve your goal by using plain `int array[]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the size of the array. The syntax is : `Type variable_name[constexpr]`.

For example:

```
class Test {
public:
    Test() : array{1, 2, 3} { 
    }

private:
    int array[3];
};
```

If you want to have a dynamically allocated array you have to use `new` and `delete`. A better alternative is: `std::vector`